# Why does my command prompt show no characters entered?

Tags: java, jline

When I execute my program and I read with either jline's ConsoleReader or with the BufferedReader the text I enter is entered but not shown. For example I type `asd`, my Console does not show `asd`, but when I hit enter, it tells me `Could not find command 'asd'. Type 'help' for help`
So the String I enter gets read, but does not show up.

Windows command prompt, start script:

```
@echo off
java -jar PixelCloud.jar
pause
```

I've tried to put my Code in a thread, use Scanner, use BufferedReader, use ConsoleReader and none worked

```
        AnsiConsole.systemInstall();
        try {
            reader = new ConsoleReader(System.in, System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        console = new ColoredConsole();
        console.sendMessage(Message.TYPE_HELP);
        String line;
        System.out.println("test");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("test2");
            Command.dispatchCommand(line);
        }
```

I expect when I type `asd`, that `asd` is shown while I type it.
My current console Output is

```
Type "help" for help.
test
test2
Could not find command 's'. Type "help" for help.
test2
Could not find command 'hello'. Type "help" for help.
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment, the `@echo off`, no prompt nor entered commands are displayed, only the output of the commands you enter;

More info at [Microsoft echo command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)

Comment: The ```@echo off``` just turns off the Messages of the Batch file, not the Input. I tried, even though, but did not work (sorry for my bad english)